# How to update the access permission using expo for iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I read expo's guides regarding applying for permission for the photo folder in the app. I added the correct strings in the app.json file       "infoPlist": {
"NSCameraUsageDescription": "My message",
"NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "My mEssage"
}
and still i am getting reject from Apple because of the content of the request
i don't know how can i edit this content, any help
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add another line:
"infoPlist": {
"NSCameraUsageDescription": "We needs camera permissions to allow you to upload profile photos.",
"NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription": "We needs photo library permissions to allow you to upload profile images.",
"NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription": "We needs photo library permissions to allow you to upload profile images."
}